# Open new database in tab from xpages

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Im trying to open a database from my server javascript in xpages, but cant seem to get it right

```
  var session:NotesSession;
  //var session = getSession();
  agentContext:NotesAgentContext = session.getAgentContext();

  // (Your code goes here) 
  db:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase("", "names.nsf");
  if (!db.isOpen()){
    System.out.println("names2.nsf does not exist on snapper");
  } else{
    System.out.println("Title of names2.nsf: \"" + db.getTitle()+ "\"") ;
  }
```

Please advice, i want when this function is called, a new tabe in notes with that database opens up

Comment: something equivalent to @Command([FileOpenDatabase]; strServer : strFilePath)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a notes://server/names2.nsf?open url and open it with the method you prefer (window.open, or whatever)... This will open a new Tab with the database you want and the start- parameters of the database. Just replace "server" with the right servername.

That way you can even mix classic development and xpages in one database, by just using db.nsf/NameOfClassicFrameset?Openframeset to override the start- parameters of the database...

Comment: Thank you, can i use the same approach with retrieving the users mail?

Comment: Yes, of course this is possible. It is even quite easy, as there are default- urls for that:****User's mail file -- Notes:///0000000000000E00
****User's address book -- Notes:///0000000000000E01
****User's subscriptions -- Notes:///0000000000000E02
****User's bookmarks -- Notes:///0000000000000E03
****Current database -- Notes:///0000000000000000

Comment: but will this work even if its on the the local server, thank you very much for your input, what happens if you dont know the current server the person is working on, is there a way i can get the server from client side javascript? cant seem to get that right

Comment: These are reserved urls. They work whenever the location document in the client is filled correctly regardless of the location of the server of the mailfile. You just use them as is. Without adding a server...

Comment: Im very new to xpages so please bare with me, can i use the ruplical id to open the database?

Comment: Please check tis link: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/notes-urls . This has nothing to do with xpages...

Comment: As Tode notes, it is just a normal Notes thing, not specific to XPages. A link like Notes://MailServer/0000000000000E00 would attempt to open the file with that replica ID on a server named "MailServer" (so, substitute the name of your server). If you use no server name, like this Notes:///0000000000000E00, with all three slashes next to each other, it just opens whichever icon is stacked on top for that replica ID.